# How to set a function value or expression over a domain in Maple

Tags: functions, maple

I have a function $f(x,y,z)$ and would like to impose the condition $$f(x,y,z)|_{x^2+y^2<1}=x-y$$ That is, $f$ is set to be equal to $x-y$ within the unit circle in the xy-plane.

How would I write this in Maple? I tried with eval but it won't allow the inequality sign.

Comment: What should it evaluate to for other values of $x$, $y$, $z$?

Comment: It is unknown; I cannot use piecewise either... Could I only set it to a value/expression over a limited domain?

Comment: In most cases, you wouldn't specify the domain of a function. How do you want to use it?

Comment: As a init/boundary condition in an ODE for $f(x,y,z)$.

Comment: An ODE is for a function of one variable, not three.  Which is the variable?

Comment: THe variable is z; if the function is $z^2$ in the above domain, it is still unknown outside of it. If it is a PDE, the problem, is still there  - how to define the domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An adjustment to mrf's tentative suggestion.

```
restart:

f:=proc(x,y,z)
      if x::numeric and y::numeric and x^2+y^2<1 then
        x-y;
      else
        'procname'(args);
      end if;
end proc:

f(a,b,c);
                       f(a, b, c)

f(1/2,1/3,z);
                           1
                           -
                           6

f(2,2,z);
                       f(2, 2, z)
```

Comment: I tried this and it works; how could I call it within dsolve as a init/boundary condition? usually, dsolve({ode},{ics}) I am unsure how to use your procedure within dsolve

Comment: I guess I can say dsolve({ode},{f}) it seems to work

Comment: Actually, the procedure works on its own, but cannot call it within dsolve. dsolve({ode},{f}) works, but ignores the procedure.

Answer (score 1):

```
f:= proc(x,y,z)
     try
          if x^2+y^2 < 1 then x-y else 'procname'(args) end if
     catch "cannot determine if this expression is true or false: ":
          'procname'(args)
     end try
end proc;
```

Comment: Tried this also; works fine just needed to add a ; after the endif and a : at the end. Same question though - how could I call it within dsolve as a init/boundary condition? usually, dsolve({ode},{ics}) I am unsure how to use your procedure within dsolve

Comment: dsolve({ode},{f}) seems to work

Comment: Actually, the procedure works on its own, but cannot call it within dsolve. dsolve({ode},{f}) works, but ignores the procedure.

Answer (score 0):

I can't quite think of a use case for this (normally, you wouldn't specify the domain of a function when using Maple), but perhaps

```
f := proc (x, y, z) if x^2+y^2 < 1 then x-y else ('f')(x, y, z) end if end proc
```

is what you're looking for? (The drawback being that `f(a,b,c)` raises an error about not being able to determine whether $a^2+b^2 < 1$.)

Comment: I need to use this to specify an initial condition for $f$. For example, $f(0,0,z)=z^2$ can easily be added to an ODE and then dsolve can use it in finding the solution; just the case above is more complicated because x and y occupy values within a domain

Comment: I tried this; it could work, only dsolve complained (as you pointed out) it cannot determine if x^2+y^2 < 1. I thought there would be an algebraic expression in Maple to do this...